# isset() multiple fields error

Tags: php, pdo

How do I check if all POST data are NOT EMPTY?

Below is my code. This allows to INSERT data even when there are blank fields.

```
$stname = $_POST['stname'];
$staddress = $_POST['staddress'];
$stbirth = $_POST['bday'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['stname'] && $_POST['staddress'] && $_POST['bday'] && $_POST['tel'] && $_POST['email'])) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO student (Student_Name, Address, Birthday, Telephone, Email) VALUES (:name, :address, :bday, :tel, :email)";
$statement = $con_db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array('name' => $stname, 'address' => $staddress, 'bday' => $stbirth, 'tel' => $tel, 'email' => $email));

if($statement){
    echo "Successful!";
} else {
    echo "Error occured...";
};
} else {
    echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}
```

I even tried the below. Did not work. What might be the issue?

```
if(isset($_POST['stname'] , $_POST['staddress'] , $_POST['bday'] , $_POST['tel'] , $_POST['email']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the IF statement and use the variable which you already have assigned. The isset should only have one variable inside of it. Because otherwise you create a new expression which will always be set and will therefore return TRUE.

```
$stname = $_POST['stname'];
$staddress = $_POST['staddress'];
$stbirth = $_POST['bday'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if($stname != '' && $staddress != '' && $stbirth != '' && $tel != '' && $email != '') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student (Student_Name, Address, Birthday, Telephone, Email) VALUES (:name, :address, :bday, :tel, :email)";
    $statement = $con_db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array('name' => $stname, 'address' => $staddress, 'bday' => $stbirth, 'tel' => $tel, 'email' => $email));

    if($statement){
        echo "Successful!";
    } else {
        echo "Error occured...";
    };
} else {
    echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}
```

Comment: Don't repost the entire code block without pointing out WHAT you changed.

Comment: Thanks. I was rather looking for the reason why the isset() did not work. Was expecting something like MarkB's answer.

Comment: Sorry. But other persons want to see the whole code lines. It should not be so hard to see that I did change the IF statement.

Comment: @FranzHolzinger Code only answers are discouraged because it isn't so obvious to beginners.

Comment: But why did you not ask?
The isset does not make sense, because you make a bracket around the whole construct with something inside.
    if(isset($_POST['stname']) && isset($_POST['staddress']) ... && isset($_POST['bday']) ... )
 You have assigned a variable for each $_POST array element. So why don't you use this in the statement?

Answer (score 0):

In `isset` you should not use `&&`. Try this..

```
if(isset($_POST['stname'] , $_POST['staddress'] , $_POST['bday'] , $_POST['tel'] , $_POST['email'])
and !empty($_POST['stname']) and !empty($_POST['staddress']) and !empty($_POST['bday']) and
!empty($_POST['tel']) and !empty($_POST['email'])
){
    //Your codes
}
```

Comment: isset() tests for the variable's existence. it doesn't tell you if there's anything IN the variables. `$foo = ''; var_dump(isset($foo))` will spit out TRUE.

Comment: @MarcB: why -1? I'm student trying to learn. That's unfair! :(

Comment: @Nelie also can use `!empty()` like my updated code.

Comment: oh no -4... I'm gone! Thanks anyway all. Appreciate all your responses. :)